# Does stackexchange support indieauth OpenID delegation

Tags: oauth

I've been following this post on [replacing-myopenid](http://peat.org/2013/09/15/replacing-myopenid/) and have setup a [github page](http://emeraldjava.github.io/) as per the instructions from [indieauth.com](https://indieauth.com/setup). I want to add 'http://emeraldjava.github.io' as an alternative open id url for my [stackoverflow account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55794/emeraldjava). Can someone explain why this login request fails?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs on meta